# How to determine the publish settings of an swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to find out the following publish settings of an swf file.
- JPEG quality
- Audio stream and Audio event

The above mentioned settings are available under the publish settings tab inside Flash. I want to find out this setting once the swf is published.

Any help in this regards is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This information dosn't exist in swf file. This settings are used when flash builds swf file and as result all are assests converted.

You can check the swf file format from [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf).